# RadioButtonList InnerHtml issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, innerhtml, radiobuttonlist

i have a div with id "divBody"

```
RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
divBody.InnerHtml += rbl;
```

also rbl has items too, which is added by

```
rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "asd", Value = "1" });
```

i cannot initialize `divBody.InnerHtml += rbl;` because for that code piece, i see this as output in website : `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection` this gotta be so easy to solve, but i don't want to initialize radiobuttonlist from .aspx page, i'd like to initialize this from .cs file.

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: What kind of class is `divBody`?

Comment: try `divBody.InnerHtml = rbi;`

Comment: divbody is a div id
`<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div ID="divBody" runat="server">
        <asp:Table ID="tableBody" runat="server">

        </asp:Table>
    </div>
</asp:Content>`

Comment: I also tried `rbl.items` but nothing changed

Comment: if i do `divbody = rbl` instead of `divbody += rbl` nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add controls from code behind you don't need to play with html just add it

```
RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "asd", Value = "1" });
//also divbody should be a panel or div with runat = server
divBody.Controls.Add(rbl);
```

Comment: yes, div is with runat = server. but i still cannot see `rbl` content even i code `divBody.Controls.Add(rbl);` on the webpage.

Comment: @DemonD now are you getting controls

Comment: It is something about database after trying your suggestion, whatever your answer helped me much, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
divBody.Controls.Add(rbl);
```

When you use `InnerHtml`, you have to set text to be rendered like below.

```
divBody.InnerHtml = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"example\" value=\"foo\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the runat="server" attribute for the div. Asp.Net will create a [HtmlControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here you can instead of setting the InnerHtml property do the following:

```
divBody.Controls.Add(rbl);
```

This will render the radiobutton list during the rendering phase of the application lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

`RadioButtonList` is a server control and we cannot add it in InnerHTML of div control. You can do it as follows:

```
RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
    rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "asd", Value = "1" });
    divBody.Controls.Add(rbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
divBody.Controls.Add(rbl);
```

solved my problem and of course, that div has to have `runat=server`

Thank you.